# Test Android application on Android Go emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-go

How can I test my application on [Android Go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Go)?

I found out that Google does not provide any emulator for Android Go.

I know that I should check the application's performance and improve it to have a better experience on Android Go, but how can I test it?

Comment: From an app devs point of view there is no difference between Go and normal Android. Create an emulator that has 2GB or less of RAM and you should be good to go.

Comment: well, on Android GO you won't ever get some permissions and features, like `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` or PiP mode. still for checking performance only common emulator with low-end preconf should be sufficient